# Which keys are the most likely to yield Forma?

Tags: warframe

High-level Warframe takes a lot of Forma. You need 1-4 Forma to build any of the clan research weapons or sentinels. You need several Forma to fit all the best mods into any weapon or frame. And the alerts that reward Forma are few & far between.

Clearly the solution to this is void/tower keys; pretty much every tower mission includes Forma in its drop list. Which keys are the most efficient for acquiring Forma, though?

Comment: Just placing this here for any future-comers: You no longer need Keys to access the Void.

Answer (score 3):

Statistically, tower IV levels yield the most forma. T4 defenses have a chance to award a blueprint at the end of each 5 rounds and survivals have a chance to award a blueprint after periods B and C. (10, 15, 25, 30, 40, 45, 55, 60,...)

Personally, I prefer to do Tower 3 survival because after every 15 minutes you have a chance of getting either a forma or a forma blueprint (or something else of course) and you you don't have to worry about Vor coming in and messing you up.

Answer (score 2):

Having not played in a while, I will be going off of my old farming methods. Use T4 or T3  Survival/Defense. You can grab a lot of Forma Blueprints, and even a couple of full built Forma.

Comment: I did Orokin Derelict Defense to get my forma. You can easily get to wave 40 with a well specced nova and vauban.